# Expandable editor in scrollview cutting text in Maui

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I am trying to create an editor field which behaves roughly like the one on Messenger. That is:

- Can expand when the user types multiple lines
- The editor can only grow to defined max height whereafter scrolling is possible within the editor

The editor will expand fine with the `AutoSize="TextChanges"` property but attempting to add scroll behavior makes the editor behave strangely.

It is defined in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor) that we can't set a `HeightRequest` on the editor while we have `AutoSize`.

Here is my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MauiHandler"
             x:Class="MauiHandler.MainPage">

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">

        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>

        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightGrey" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></BoxView>

        <StackLayout Padding="8, 12"
                     BackgroundColor="White">
            <Grid Padding="12, 6"
                  ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto"
                  ColumnSpacing="10"
                  RowDefinitions="Auto">

                <ScrollView Grid.Column="0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                            MaximumHeightRequest="150">

                    <Editor BackgroundColor="White"
                            AutoSize="TextChanges"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            Keyboard="Chat"
                            Placeholder="Aa"
                            TextColor="Gray"></Editor>
                </ScrollView>
                
                <Button Text="Send"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        VerticalOptions="End"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
 
</ContentPage>
```

The view:

[image]

Typing in some text:

[image]

Exceeding the scrollheight:

[image]

In the last picture the first text inserted in the second picture (*Aaaaa*) is "cut off" from the scroll-view.

Comment: Explain exactly what you expected to happen differently. You told scrollview not to allow vertical scrolling.

Comment: @TooolmakerSteve Do you mean `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"`? That's just the visibility as far as I know and doesn't disable scrolling itself. Either way the issue persists when removing that attribute: The editor seems to cut off text when too much text is inserted. Notice that the scroll container is fully scrolled to the top at picture #3 but "Aaaa" line from picture #2 is cut off.

Comment: If you scroll back to the beginning is it there? Both Android and iOS text entry elements are defined (by the platforms' OS) to always have the cursor position visible. So user sees what they type. If text is entered, then the cursor will be at the end of the text. When that end character is visible, with its cursor, the starting characters are obviously scrolled off the top. Are you saying you want the start characters not to be scrolled off the top? The only way to do that, is to move the cursor there. But that means characters would be entered there. I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I do expect the text to be scrolled off at the top. The issue is that it is not simply scrolled off - it is literally cut off and unreachable by the scrollview. In #3 I have scrolled all the way to the top but the first line is now cut off. Notice in #3 the scrollbar is all the way to the top but the first line is not present (see the 1st line in picture #2 with aaa)

Comment: Please see this reproduction repo https://github.com/jonakirke94/maui-editor-scroll-reproduction or see the issue in this video: https://ctrlv.tv/t0V1

Comment: The issue appears to be that the Editor cannot grow larger than the scrollview (i.e 75 DP). It's quite interesting that it works with hot-reload if you change the `MaximumHeightRequest` is changed to `151` for example, while the application is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of frustation I figured out that the ScrollView did not properly register the changes of the content.

I solved it by (at least on Android) by adding the following to the code-behind file:

```
// There is a mismatch between these values. They should be equal.
// It appears the autosize does not update the inner scroll view
Console.WriteLine($"ContentSize of the ScrollView: {InnerScrollView.ContentSize}");
Console.WriteLine($"ContentSize of the Editor: {MyEditor.DesiredSize}");

 // Trigger a new layout in the scroll view. After this the content size and desired size will be equal
 Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => InnerScrollView.ForceLayout());
```

It may not be the most performant solution, but it works!